# ASP.NET MVC Preview 5 & Resharper weirdness

Tags: asp.net-mvc, resharper

I've just created my first Preview 5 error and it doesn't seem to place nice with Resharper.  All the C# in the Views are coming up with errors, things like <%= Html.Password("currentPassword") %> has the "currentPassword" highlighted with the following error: Argument type "System.String" is not assignable parameter type "string".

IList errors = ViewData["errors"] as IList; has the IList highlighted as "Can not resole symbol 'string'"

Has anyone seen this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try [latest nightly build](http://www.jetbrains.net/confluence/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+4.0+Nightly+Builds) of ReSharper 4.1? In some cases the bug in 4.1 manifests itself with numerous ambiguity errors, and it has been fixed within the follow up build.

Comment: I'm on nightly 933, for some reason I thought I was an an release, need to remember to try them first before I start moaning!

Comment: Installing the latest nightly sorted it, but it reset Visual Studio to defaults and cleared all my Live/File Templates!

Comment: Chris, this shouldn't happen, we will try to reproduce it. It would be nice if you can tell us what templates did you have (live/file/surround), for which languages, shared or not, etc. Thanks for the info and sorry for inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone finds this blog, the fix suggested above worked for me - I downloaded the latest 4.1 build, and the ambiguous reference problem is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this can occur when you don't fully qualify your Inherits attribute of your @Page directive. Even if it is in your web.config be sure and fully qualify your Inherits directive for R#. (At least as of build 4.1.943).

This bug has been reported here:
http://www.jetbrains.net/jira/browse/RSRP-96241